# jQuery - update length live, not on pageload only

Tags: jquery, checkbox, count

I have a large form on my site which contains a lot of checkboxes. A small jQuery script is counting the number of unchecked checkboxes and outputs the length in the HTML.

I use this:

```
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    var BoxesUnchecked = $('section.gearset input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length;
                    $('h3.gs-hook').html('The are ' + BoxesUnchecked + ' unchecked Items');
                });
```

The checked-state of the checkboxes is saved via cookie. My problem is that the above script only updates after page reload. But I want the length to change whenever another checkbox is checked or unchecked. Basically a live update of the length value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create one function which will call on both onpage load and onclick of any checkbox. See the below answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 retChkVal();
 function retChkVal()
 {
 //alert();
 var BoxesUnchecked = $('input:checkbox:not(":checked")').length;
 $('.gs-hook').html('The are ' + BoxesUnchecked + ' unchecked Items');
 }
 
 jQuery("[name=foo]").click(function(source) { 
 //alert();
   retChkVal();
});
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>

<div class="gs-hook">



</div>
```

Comment: Ohh that's really Great.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        var BoxesUnchecked = $('section.gearset input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length;
        $('h3.gs-hook').html('The are ' + BoxesUnchecked + ' unchecked Items');
});
```

Comment: If I use this, then only on clicking a checkbox the function is triggered. But nothing is displayed on initial pageload anymore.